# mongodump via vmc tunnel to cloudfoundry hangs up

Tags: mongodb, cloud-foundry, vmc, mongodump

For some reason the process of the mongodump via tunnel hangs up at the same collection each time. If I break the process, files with collection has size near 39Mb. I can't understand what's happened.

Comment: You're more likely to get useful answers if you can provide some small part of the code to which you've narrowed down the problem.  Otherwise it's hard for others to see what might be going wrong.

Comment: Any error information if available would be helpful. If you received no error information you could be experiencing the 3 second timeout. CF is working on features which will solve the timeout issue. Stay tuned to http://cloudfoundry.com for new features as cloudfoundry evolves.

Comment: I asked for only for ideas. And I can say that the problem is that mongodump via tunnel on cloudfoundry hangs in case some collection has a big size. Sorry, I didn't find the solution and just create programatical export of my DB. Thanks in any case.